# Android dynamic viewpager with fragments example

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am a new Bee in Android development.Could any one share a code snippet which demonstrates how to add new pages to viewpager with fragments.

Example: Intially there should a default page and then clicking on a button user should be able to add n number of pages etc.

I have gone through the some of the posts in this site but I am not understanding them correctly.

Please help.

Thanks & Regards,
Aditya.J

Answer (score 0):

visit link that explains demo
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/04/android-tutorial-using-the-viewpager.html